# determine posts per page in second loop wpQuery

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

I have multiple loops using wp_query() in WordPress.

I want to show the posts from first loop first (post per page=10),

and if there are no posts from first loop show, then show the second loop.

For example, if I only have 8 posts from first loop, the second loop should show 2 posts.

The loop is working properly, but I can't solve the post per page issue. How can I do this? I also need pagination for the remaining posts.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'event',
            'event-categories'  => 'featured',
            'orderby'           =>  'meta_value_num', 
            'order'             =>  'ASC',

        );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$args1 = array(
            'post_type'         => 'event',
                    'event-categories'  => 'abc'
            'orderby'       =>  'meta_value_num', 
                    'order'             =>  'ASC',

        );

$loop1 = new WP_Query( $args1);
```

Comment: This has been asked and solved dozens and dozens of times: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpagination%5D+error+is%3Aq

Comment: apart from pagination, number posts to be desplayed how to be determined?

Comment: I don't know, Nisham... If I were to solve this, or help you to solve, I would start with the search query above ^^^^ **I'm positive** you'll find a solution there. Good luck!